# Execute Lines of code when needed

Tags: spring, velocity

I have a @ModelAttribute that I am calling from another method showHome.

```
@ModelAttribute
    public void getAuthority(@ModelAttribute InputDataType authorityCreatedRequest, CountyInputDataType countryCreatedRequest, ParishInputDataType parishCreatedRequest, Model model)
    {

        model.addAttribute("authorityCreatedRequest", new ObjectFactory().createInputDataType());       
        CrrAuthorityResponseType authorityCreatedResponse = new ObjectFactory().createCrrAuthorityResponseType();
        authorityCreatedResponse = (CrrAuthorityResponseType) ((JAXBElement<?>) rdwebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(authorityCreatedRequest)).getValue();        
        model.addAttribute("authorityCreatedResponse", authorityCreatedResponse);
        authorityList.clear();
        authorityList.add( authorityCreatedResponse );      
        model.addAttribute("authorityList", authorityList);      
    }
```

the problem is the modelattribute is executing 2 times. I don't want to execute it more than once. Is there any other way better than @ModelAttribute that I can execute lines of code where I need that.

```
@RequestMapping
    public String showHome(@ModelAttribute InputDataType authorityCreatedRequest, CountyInputDataType countryCreatedRequest, ParishInputDataType parishCreatedRequest, Model model)
    {


       model.addAttribute("authorityList", authorityList);      



       return "crownreservereport"; 
    }
```

Comment: Don't call it. `@ModelAttribute` annotated methods are automatically called before any request handling methods. No need to call it manually.

Comment: @M. Deinum thanks for the info. I deleted the line model.addAttribute("authorityList", authorityList);  inside the showHome method. I am still getting my authority list but if I take a look inside tcp/ip monitor i can see getAuthority is executing multiple times. how can i stop that?

Comment: As I mentioned `@ModelAttribute` annotated methods are executed before each request handling method. If you controller has 2 methods which are invoked (for instance rendering the response is another method) you will also get 2 calls the the `@ModelAttribute` annotated method.

Comment: Thanks @M. Deinum. Now I got it.